# What is Object relational mapping(ORM) levels in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I've came across this question a couple of times when searching for jobs, but, when developing, I never come across this terminology anywhere. I know they are 4 levels in it, but does it really matter for me to know what it is? As an application designer, should I know this? Can somebody explain this with real world scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The four levels are

- -**Pure relational ORM** The entire application, including the user interface, is designed around the relational model and SQL-based
  relational operations.

  -**Light object mapping** The entities are represented as classes that are mapped manually to the relational
  tables. The code is hidden from the business logic using specific
  design patterns. This approach is successful for applications with a
  less number of entities, or applications with common, metadata-driven
  data models. This approach is most known to all.

  -**Medium object mapping** The application is designed around an object model. The SQL code is generated at build
  time. And the associations between objects are supported by the
  persistence mechanism, and queries are specified using an
  object-oriented expression language. This is best suited for
  medium-sized applications with some complex transactions. Used when
  the mapping exceeds 25 different database products at a time.

  -**Full object mapping** Full object mapping supports sophisticated object modeling: composition, inheritance, polymorphism
  and persistence. The persistence layer implements transparent
  persistence; persistent classes do not inherit any special base class
  or have to implement a special interface. Efficient fetching
  strategies and caching strategies are implemented transparently to
  the application.

  - See more at: http://www.javabeat.net/hibernate-interview-questions/#sthash.6ku1UliM.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

The four levels are:

- Pure Relational
- Light Object Mapping
- Medium Object Mapping
- Full Object Mapping

Have a look more specifically into the hibernate docs for detail on each of them.

Comment: Thanks KepaniHaole, I'm looking for a realworldy examples on this.

Comment: Also, I did not find anything in the hibernate docs. Could you please direct me to the document?

Comment: @Zeus Here, have a look at this. Specifically numbers 5 through 8: http://www.javabeat.net/2009/02/hibernate-interview-questions/#